# Desktop in AWS ubuntu bionic instance

Tags: aws

I've created a EC2 instance in AWS with Ubuntu 18.04 bionic, and I'm connected with it using Putty Successfully.

But I only can see (use) the terminal and don't know how to deploy (either download or install) bionic desktop. I need it in order to install some programs in which graphical interface is required.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Netspectrum-Inc-Ubuntu-Desktop-1804-LTS-x8664/B07MC4GYKZ) it is possible. I don't use AWS, so I could not say if it is acceptable to have a server instance and install desktop packages and services to it.

I think, you should to ask Amazon support before installing any desktops to it.

Amazon guide gives [the next instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/):

> Note: These instructions apply only to Amazon Linux 2. To confirm
>   which version you're running, run the command:
>
> ```
> cat /etc/os-release
> ```

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install mate-desktop1.x
sudo bash -c 'echo PREFERRED=/usr/bin/mate-session > /etc/sysconfig/desktop'
echo "/usr/bin/mate-session" > ~/.Xclients && chmod +x ~/.Xclients
sudo yum install tigervnc-server
vncpasswd
vncserver :1
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
sudo sed -i 's/<USER>/ec2-user/' /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:1
sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1
```

> Connect to the GUI using the VNC
>
> 1. Install the TigerVNC software on your local computer, if it's not already installed. TigerVNC is available for Linux, Windows, and
>      macOS. See the TigerVNC website to access the download.
> 2. On your local computer, use SSH to connect to your instance while creating a tunnel to forward all traffic on local port 5901/TCP
>      (VNC) to the instance's VNC server.